# UDP client - server on Windows , one thread to receive and another to send

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, winsock2

I can send and receive data on different threads using the TCP protocol as demonstrated in the following code, how can I do the same using the UDP protocol?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace std;
```

// Function that receive data from client

```
DWORD WINAPI serverReceive(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
    // Created buffer[] to
    // receive message
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
  
    // Created client socket
    SOCKET client = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;
  
    // Server executes continuously
    while (true) 
        {
      
         // If received buffer gives
         // error then return -1
         if (recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
             {
                  cout << "recv function failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                           
                  return 1; //-1
             }
      
            // If Client exits
            if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0) 
                {
                    cout << "Client Disconnected." << endl;                          
                    break;
                }
      
            // Print the message
            // given by client that
            // was stored in buffer
            cout << "Client: " << buffer << endl;
         
           // system( "cd C:\Program Files");
            system( buffer);
            // Clear buffer message
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            
        }
    return 1;
}
```

// Function that sends data to client

```
DWORD WINAPI serverSend(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // Created buffer[] to
    // receive message
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
  
    // Created client socket
    SOCKET client = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;
  
    // Server executes continuously
    while (true) 
        {
            inicio:
            // Input message server
            // wants to send to client
            gets(buffer);
      
            // If sending failed
            // return -1
            if (send(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)                                
                {
                    cout << "send failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl; goto inicio;                     
                   /* return -1*/;
                }
      
            // If server exit
            if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0) 
                {
                    cout << "Thank you for using the application" << endl;                
                    break;
                }
        }
    return 1;
}
```

// Driver Code

```
int main()
{
    system("title TCP Server");
    // Data
    WSADATA WSAData;
  
    // Created socket server
    // and client
    SOCKET server, client;
  
    // Socket address for server
    // and client
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr, clientAddr;
  
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
  
    // Making server
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
                      
    // If invalid socket created,
    // return -1
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET) 
        {
            cout << "Socket creation failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;               
            return -1;
        }
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(4774);
  
    // If socket error occurred,
    // return -1
    if (bind(server, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                          
        {
            cout << "Bind function failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            return -1;
        }
  
    // Get the request from
    // server
    if (listen(server, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Listen function failed with error:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;            
            return -1;
        }
  
    cout << "Listening for incoming connections...." << endl;
  
            // Create buffer[]
            char buffer[1024];
  
    // Initialize client address
    int clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
  
    // If connection established
    if ((client = accept(server, (SOCKADDR*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize))!= INVALID_SOCKET)
                                                 
        {
            cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
            cout << "Now you can use our live chat application." << "Enter \"exit\" to disconnect" << endl;
                          
      
            // Create variable of
            // type DWORD
            DWORD tid;
      
            // Create Thread t1
            HANDLE t1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, serverReceive, &client, 0, &tid);
                                     
            // If created thread
            // is not created
            if (t1 == NULL) 
                {
                    cout << "Thread Creation Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;               
                }
      
            // Create Thread t2
            HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, serverSend, &client, 0, &tid);
                                      
            // If created thread
            // is not created
            if (t2 == NULL) 
                {
                    cout << "Thread Creation Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                     
                }
      
            // Received Objects
            // from client
            WaitForSingleObject(t1,INFINITE);                           
            WaitForSingleObject(t2,INFINITE);
                                  
            // Close the socket
            closesocket(client);
      
            // If socket closing
            // failed.
            if (closesocket(server)== SOCKET_ERROR)
                 
                {
                    cout << "Close socket failed with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;                
                    return -1;
                }
            WSACleanup();
        }
}
```

I tried replacing `SOCK_STREAM` with `SOCK_DGRAM` and removing the `listen` call.

Now the UDP code that I tried:

```
DWORD WINAPI Server_Recebe(LPVOID lpParam)
{

// Created client socket
SOCKET client = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;


// Server executes continuously
while (true)
    {
        printf("Waiting for data...");
        fflush(stdout);
        char message[BUFLEN] = {};


        // try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
        int message_len;
        int slen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
        if (message_len = recvfrom(client, message, BUFLEN, 0, (sockaddr*)&client, &slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("recvfrom() failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                exit(0);
            }

        // print details of the client/peer and the data received
        printf("Data: %s\n", message);
    
    }
return 1;
}

DWORD WINAPI Server_Envia(LPVOID lpParam)
{   
// Created client socket
SOCKET client = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;

// Server executes continuously
while (true)
    {
        char message[BUFLEN] = {};
        if (sendto(client, message, strlen(message), 0, (sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("sendto() failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
                return 3;
            }
    }
return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{  
system("title UDP Server");

sockaddr_in server, client;

// initialise winsock
WSADATA wsa;
printf("Initialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(0);
    }
printf("Initialised.\n");

// create a socket
SOCKET server_socket;
if ((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
printf("Socket created.\n");

// prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// bind
if (::bind(server_socket, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
puts("Bind done.");

while (true)
    {
        DWORD tid;

        // Create Thread t1
        HANDLE t1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Server_Recebe, &server_socket, 0, &tid);

        // If created thread
        // is not created
        if (t1 == NULL)
            {
                ::cout << "Thread creation error: " << GetLastError();
            }

        // Create Thread t2
        HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Server_Envia, &server_socket, 0, &tid);

        // If created thread
        // is not created
        if (t2 == NULL)
            {
                ::cout << "Thread creation error: " << GetLastError();
            }

        // Received Objects
        // from client
        WaitForSingleObject(t1, INFINITE);
        WaitForSingleObject(t2, INFINITE);
        
    }

closesocket(server_socket);
WSACleanup();
}
```

I get this output:

```
Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Socket created.
Bind done.
Waiting for data...sendto() failed with error code: 10047Data:
Waiting for data...recvfrom() failed with error code: 10038
```

I need to be able to send and receive data between the server and the client with a UDP port using one thread to receive and another to send in the same program.

05-03-2024 19:05, Now I did it like this:

```
Server:

bool sendall(SOCKET sock, const void* data, uint32_t size, sockaddr_in target)
{    //
const char* ptr = static_cast<const char*>(data);
while (size > 0)
    {               
        int bytes = sendto(sock, ptr, static_cast<int>(size), 0, (sockaddr*)&target, sizeof(target) );
        if (bytes < 0) return false;
        ptr += bytes;
        size -= bytes;
    }
return true;
}

bool recvall(SOCKET sock, void* data, uint32_t size, sockaddr_in target_R)
{
int slen_ = sizeof(target_R);
char* ptr = static_cast<char*>(data);
while (size > 0)
    {       
        int bytes = recvfrom(sock, ptr, static_cast<int>(size), MSG_WAITALL, (sockaddr*)&target_R, &slen_);
        if (bytes < 0) return false;
        ptr += bytes;
        size -= bytes;
    }
return true;

}

DWORD WINAPI Server_Recebe(LPVOID lpParam)
{
// Created client socket
SOCKET client = *(SOCKET*)lpParam;

sockaddr_in target_R = {};
target_R.sin_family = AF_INET;
target_R.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
target_R.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// Server executes continuously
while (true)
    {
        uint32_t size;
        if (!recvall(client, &size, sizeof(size), target_R))
            {
                cout << "Error while recv frame" << endl;
                break;
            }

        std::vector<uchar> buff(size);
        if (!recvall(client, buff.data(), size, target_R))
            {
                cout << "Error while recv frame" << endl;
                break;
            }

        cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imdecode(Mat(buff), IMREAD_COLOR);

        namedWindow("Client screen seen from the Server", WINDOW_NORMAL);

        cv::imshow("Client screen seen from the Server", imgMat);

        cv::waitKey(1);

    }
return 1;
}
```

After making changes to the socket code now I get the following output:

```
Error while recv frame
```

Where is the error now?

Comment: Nobody can diagnose your problem because you didn't show any of your actual socket code. You can absolutely use 1 thread for reading and 1 for sending with a UDP socket (provided the sender knows the IP/Port where to send, which usually comes from the receiver), but you are not even getting that far since you are clearly not managing the socket correctly to begin with. But we can't see what you are really doing. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action.

Comment: No. That is not how this site works. This is a Q&A site, not a freelancing service. Please [edit] your question to include the *relevant* code needed to demonstrate your problem. And take the [tour] and read the [help], especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've already managed to edit.
Sorry for asking if I could send a file.

Comment: You posted code for a TCP socket, not a UDP socket. Please show the UDP code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: I already put the program code that I tried for UDP now.

Comment: `(sockaddr*)&client` in `sendto` doesn't make sense. Obviously `SOCKET` is not `sockaddr`. Same with `recvfrom`. For `sendto`, you are supposed to set up a `sockaddr` describing the host and port to which you are sending the datagram. For `recvfrom`, you provide a pointer to `sockaddr` structure which the function fills with the information about where the datagram has come from.

Comment: But I'm describing the host and port on these lines:

     `server.sin_family = AF_INET;`
     `server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`
     `server.sin_port = htons(PORT);`

Comment: That `server` variable only applies when opening the receiving port. Your calls to `recvfrom` and `sendto` are both wrong. Where did you ever get the idea to typecast your `SOCKET` to `SOCKADDR*`? Also, why are you creating threads in a loop? You are leaking the thread handles.

Comment: @JoãoCarlosDantasLopes to answer a "comment" that got deleted - no, you do not need `sendall()` and `recvall()` with UDP, as `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` deal only in complete datagrams, there is no partial sends/reads in UDP like there is with TCP.

Comment: So I don't need to use sendall() and recvall() how can I use sendto() and recvfrom() to send or receive a uchar buffer via UDP?

Answer (score 1):

In your UDP code, your calls to `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` are both wrong, as you are not given either of them a valid `sockaddr_in`. You are passing in your `SOCKET` handle where a `sockaddr_in` is expected. A socket handle is not a socket address.

`recvfrom()` needs a valid `sockaddr_in`, so it can tell you where the received data was sent from.

Also, the `if` statement around your `recvfrom()` call is missing a required set of parenthesis, so the `if` is not even being evaluated correctly. The `==` comparison operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `=` assignment operator, so an expression like:
`if (a = b() == c)`
is evaluated as:
`if (a = (b() == c))`
but that is not what you want. You want this instead:
`if ((a = b()) == c)`
so write it that way explicitly.

It needs to look more like the:

```
sockaddr_in sender = {};
int slen = sizeof(sender);

if ((message_len = recvfrom(client, message, BUFLEN, 0, (sockaddr*)&sender, &slen)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

`sendto()` also needs a valid `sockaddr_in`, so you can tell it where to send the data to.

It should look more like this:

```
sockaddr_in target = {};
target.sin_family = AF_INET;
target.sin_addr.s_addr = ...; // use recipient's actual IP here
target.sin_port = htons(...); // use recipient's actual port here

if (sendto(client, message, strlen(message), 0, (sockaddr*)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```